# The integral paths and branch cuts for the irrational functions

Tags: complex-integration, branch-cuts

For the integrand function $$\frac{e^{-A\sqrt{s}}}{(\sqrt{s}+B)(s-C)\sqrt{s+\theta_c}}$$,
I defined the integral path as in the picture. Is it correct? There are two discontinuity points between
$\gamma_4$ and $\gamma_5$, $\gamma_7$ and $\gamma_8$ with respect to the argument.
I think the paths (branch cuts) for $\sqrt{s}$ and $\sqrt{s-\theta_c}$ are distinguished and can not be unified into one.

[image]

Comment: "Is it correct" is not something we can answer, as you've not mentioned what this integral path is supposed to accomplish. Thus we know nothing of the requirements upon it, other than presumably that the function actually be integrable upon it.

Comment: I just want to know if there are two branch points (two branch cuts), how to define the paths and arguments？ Is there  unified path and argument?

Comment: But once again, you have not said what it is you are attempting to accomplish with the path. Without that, **we cannot say** if there are two branch points or branch cuts or how to define the paths and arguments or anything else. You have to tell us the problem you are trying to solve, not *just* the steps you've taken, before we can determine what is correct.